# How to type snippet keywords when you need it

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I am new to vim, I just wonder if I want to actually type the keyword in some cases, how do I do it? Do I need to disable the snippets?
For example, if I use `impd` as keyword for `import pandas as pd`, then how do I actually type `impd` without triggering the snippet? 
I am using Plugin Ultisnip, 
here's the relevant part in my `.vimrc`

```
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'  
Plug 'honza/vim-snippets' 
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<tab>' 
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger ='<tab>' 
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = '<s-tab>' 
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["UltiSnips"]
```

And I config the plugin with the following two snippets for LaTeX copied from internet:

```
snippet beg "begin{} / end{}" bA
\begin{$1}
    $0
\end{$1}
endsnippet

snippet mk "Math" wA
$${1}$`!p
if t[2] and t[2][0] not in [',', '.', '?', '-', ' ']:
    snip.rv = ' '
else:
    snip.rv = ''
`$2
endsnippet
```

Then the behavior is: the snippet `beg` only triggers if I type it in a new line, and `mk` triggers no matter where I type, is there a way to, say, type "mk" without triggering it or disabling the snippet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those snippets mentioned in the question have the **auto-expand option** enabled, as there is an 'A' included in the options of each snippet (eg. `bA`, `wA`). To disable auto-expansion of a snippet, remove the 'A'. For example,

```
snippet mk "Math" w
$${1}$`!p
if t[2] and t[2][0] not in [',', '.', '?', '-', ' ']:
    snip.rv = ' '
else:
    snip.rv = ''
`$2
endsnippet
```

Now, with `<tab>` as the trigger, typing `mk` stays as is, but `mk<tab>` expands to `$$`, with the cursor in between the `$`s.

For more information, have a look at the various snippet options `:h Ultisnips-snippet-options` (you may need to run `:helptags ALL` before this).

Comment: Thank you for your generous help!